# Views broken when username contains special characters

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I've created a couple views showing e.g. the latest news and events. However, when the username contains "special characters" (but still common in Finland), for example 'ä' or 'ö', the view shows the empty text instead of the real data.

For example my events view has two fields (node title and time of the event) and three filters (published = yes, node type = event and event time >= now). Nothing closely related filtering with the username added by myself.

Is there a workaround to get the view working?

Comment: Do these usernames show up correct in the rest of Drupal? Drupal itself usually has no problems with my name (Bèr) unless I have the character encoding horribly wrong. If Drupal handles them correctly, views has a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with character encoding. I would recommend UTF8, works with almost every language.

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Whatever you do, make sure you use always the same encoding and use it everywhere.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to not use UTF-8 in Drupal. The system actually outputs UTF-8 Content-type headers twice (see http://drupal.org/node/451304) as a security precaution. Not sure how this could be the issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Drupal, but what would you recommend? By the way, I would consider the lack of support for utf8 a bug...